How to extract content correctly from all kind of rss feeds
I'm a well experienced developer, or almost this is what i was thinking before facing this problem. It look so easy to me but i cannot make it work the right way.
I have a list of feed rss, users can add their own feeds to their profile so i need to make something that works even with strange formats, because are all differents.
This is what i need to extract:

title
post date
post description
image, if there is one
video, if there is one

This is what i tried:
First: search for the right rss tags containing those data
Next: for any not found data, check an html tag via regex that might contain it (link or videos, images, img tags in the whole post xml while reading it all as a string)
Well i can't figure out a better solution. It is a short description but the code to do that is so long that i think there will be for sure a better way. because this way i still cannot get most of the fields i want or when i display something is all broken because the xml of the feeds contain HTML and so on.
Feed rss are really misunderstood because it should be a standard, seems like everyone put whatever they want inside their feed.

Why not to share a sample of non-standard data?

Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a Stacksnippet

because there are too many different data.
